# WSO2 Governance Registry: setting lifecycle state via API?

Tags: api, registry, wso2, lifecycle

I have configured the following custom lifecycle in the registry. States and transitions are shown below:

```
in.design (initial)
   -> in.development
   -> in.production
   -> in.text
in.development
   -> in.test
in.test
   -> released
released
   -> in.production
in.production
   -> deprecated
deprecated
   -> retired (end)
```

use case:
batch reconciliation for artifacts, which are managed actively in a different system.

problem:
I need to set "in.production" state via API for certain artifacts.

I have looked at the following possibilities;
* GenericArtifact API, with which I can attach a Lifecycle to an artifact. => you cannot set the Lifecycle-State
* "CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminService", but it is rather an internal API and is UI driven. Hard to program, it seems.

so the question is :
Is there a way to set the lifecycle state of an artifact to a state, which is not the initial one?

my own answer (is there a better solution?):

```
// When "simulating" the behaviour of the UI, the following works. It feels a little awkward and looks brittle to me. Found out how to use it via debugger.
CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminServiceStub clc = ...
// these are representing the check boxes in the UI
String[] params = { "false", "true", "false" };         
clc.invokeAspect(path, lifecycleName, "to.production", params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently 'CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminService' is the way to do this. However, state transition capability will be introduced to governance API [1] in a future release. That will provide a much cleaner approach.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-837